# MATLAB - extrapolation of surface in an image based on nearset neighbour

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a 2D grayscale image, mostly filled with zeros.
Within that image I have a single convex connected component, which doesn't contains zeros.

I would like to perform extrapolation of the surface of the connected component which is based on the values of it's surface.
In other words, I would like to replace the zeros by values, s.t. each pixel will get the value of the closest boundary pixel.

I tried to use interp2, but it didn't fit to my problem. I also wanted to use pdist2 in order to find pairs of closest points but I don't have the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox.

**Toy example**

input:

A =

```
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     2     5     2     0
 0     1     1     8     0
 0     7     4     4     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

desired output:

A =

```
 2     2     5     2     2
 2     2     5     2     2
 1     1     1     8     8
 7     7     4     4     4
 7     7     4     4     4
```

*Notice that in the toy example, the zero padding is thin, but it can also be much wider. Also, the connected component is not necessarily a rectangle.

Thanks!

Comment: Will your single connected component always be a block?

Comment: @BillBokeey No, it can be any type of shape

Comment: @drorco If it can be of any shape, how do you select values around corners? For example, given `A = [1 0 10;  10 20 30; 30 40 50]`, what should be the value of `A(1, 2)`? What if the shape is more complex? Are you sure that you do not want a better extrapolation method? Take a look at [inpaint_nans](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551-inpaint-nans). Let me know if you would like me to provide full code based on this function for extrapolation.

Comment: Do you have the Image Processing Toolbox?

Comment: @user1391279 - Thank you for you comment, that's a good question, In this case, a value of either  1,10 or 20 will considered as correct (it doesn't matter which). I did try inpaint_nans, but the results didn't much to the output example. Also, it doesn't work in cases were the connected component is relatively small.

Comment: @beaker - yes, I do have this toolbox.

Comment: Deleting my answer until I can come up with something that fills all the zeros. If your connected component was guaranteed to be convex, that would help, but if it can be concave then you're going to have to do some degree of inpainting.

Comment: @beaker - in this case, I can work with convex connected component. I will modify my question accordingly.

Comment: @drorco I still believe that the algorithm is either under-defined or may not produce the result that you expect in more complex cases. It is not an issue to satisfy the condition of having every element surrounding the boundary to have the value of the closest element to the boundary (a recursive pass?). However, any algorithm I can think of can produce strange results far from the boundary, i.e. fill most of the elements away from the boundary with the same value. I think I might be able to you help in a better way if you could explain the purpose of what you are trying to do,